# How to remove snps with missing names

Tags: genetics, bcftools

I have 1000 G data set which is in PLINK format, there are  some snps with names as `"."`, is there any way in PLINK i can remove that snps?

I tried bcftool view which does not work correctly.

Comment: have you tried option `--exclude my_snps.txt` where `my_snps.txt` contains the names of the SNPs that you want to exclude, such as `"."`?

Comment: How i can filter the SNPs with names "."? is there any direct command in PLINK or i should try something else?

Comment: `--exclude` is documented on the PLINK website [here](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/filter). You should just need a single column of text, one line per SNP. In your case, one line should contain exactly `.`

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command

```
 plink --bfile $YOUR_GENOTYPE_FILE --extract SNPS_TO_EXCLUDE.txt --make-bed --out $NEW_GENOTYPE_FILE
```

where the `$` variables are your desired PLINK BED/BIM/BAM file prefixes.

What does `SNPS_TO_EXCLUDE.txt` look like? From the [PLINK website](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/filter):

> `--extract` normally accepts a text file with a list of variant IDs (usually one per line, but it's okay for them to just be separated by spaces), and removes all unlisted variants from the current analysis.
>
> `--exclude` does the same for all listed variants.

Thus, `SNPS_TO_EXCLUDE.txt` should contain a line with "`.`".

Comment: Thanks! all sorted

Comment: Good to hear! If this answered your question, then please accept the answer